# Django flush won't load fixtures

Tags: django, django-fixtures

When I run `python manage.py flush` fixtures inside app wont load.

The result I'm getting is:

```
...    
Are you sure you want to do this?

        Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
    Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
    Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? My django version is `1.8.2`

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem...

Answer (score 0):

it's not flushing the data from the disk, it's flushing the data from the test database that was setup to run your tests.